# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'remove'

Tags: python, attributes

Hi everyone I am trying to create a program that takes the minimum score and removes it and averages the others and gives the result but when I tried to use the remove function to remove the minimum number I encountered this error

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 6, in 
datos.remove(min) #que esta mal?
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'remove'

this is my code

```
 def datos(nota1, nota2, nota3, nota4, nota5):
  min = datos[0]
  for i in datos:
    if(min>i):
      min=i
datos.remove(min) #what is wrong?
prom = 0
for i in datos:
  prom+=i/len(datos)%prom
print(datos('AA0010276',40, 50, 39, 76, 96))
```

I'm new to Python so I don't really know how it works, I would appreciate any input to correct this error :D

PS: some parts of the code are in Spanish

Comment: FWIW, assuming `datos` is a list, you can just do `min(datos)`

Comment: The code in your question is incomplete and the indentation is messed up. Please fix it and make sure you provide a proper [mcve].

Comment: Tell us what the code is supposed to do because it's not really apparent from the code provided

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically yout program is all wrong.

See a working example:

```
def remove_minimum_and_calculate_average(notes:list )-> float:
    return sum(notes[1:])/len(notes[1:])
```

---

```
notes = [1,5,10]

print(remove_minimum_and_calculate_average(notes))
```

---

```
7.5
```

Comment: This assumes that the minimum is the first element, which is a wrong assumption according to OP's code

Comment: I am seeing that if my program is wrong but I see that your code is rooted to a list but if we eliminate that list and put the numbers in the print the system will say:
TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 0):

You are treating datos like a list object, which it is not. It is a function, it does not support iterating over it, nor does it have remove attribute.